# Library not found for -lBVLinearGradient

Tags: javascript, react-native

I upgrade my project from 59.9 to 61.2 then I got an error about

```
Library not found for -lBVLinearGradient
```

This is my podfile:
[image]
this is my Xcode workplace

I did add to link binary with libraries doesn't work

Comment: https://imgur.com/No2MkGn

Comment: https://imgur.com/TRTzuEI
https://imgur.com/3hmFjN9

Comment: https://imgur.com/c7wUqdI

Comment: Hi - You should edit your post to include those images (not the links) in the right order, so that its easier to help you (and more clear what is what)